# emacs: how to insert an HTML entity reference?

Tags: emacs

Just now I was fumbling around on the  keyboard and saw a `&#127;` appear in the emacs buffer.

How'd I do that?

That would be handy, if I could do it on purpose.

Comment: What's your editing mode?  Take a look at the help-page for the mode, it'll show you the key-bindings.

Comment: html-mode binds C-c C-n to sgml-name-char, which is probably what you did.

Comment: Aidan, you should post that as an answer, I think.

Comment: C-c C-n SPC in html-mode here inserts "&nbsp;", not "&#127;".  Also useful, but perhaps different from what he did?

Comment: I'm using xml mode.  And yes, C-c C-n <keystroke> does it.

Comment: @Ken:  C-c C-n <backspc> inserts the entity I saw.

Comment: Ah, that's because I'm an idiot!  D'oh.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every editing mode has a help page, which you can see through `C-h m` (when you're in that mode) or `C-h f <mode-name>` when in another mode.  The mode's help-page shows you the current key-bindings.  Looking through the help-page for html-mode, I see `C-c C-n` is bound to `sgml-name-char`, which looks likely to perform the function you describe.

Answer (score 5):

You can hit C-h l (L) to see your last N keystrokes. The dump looks like:

```
<backspace> <right> C-x C-s <down> <down> <down> <down>
<down> <down> <down> <down> <down> <down> <down> <down>
<down> <down> <down> <down> <down> <down> <down> <down>
<down> <down> <C-kp-8> <f12> <down> <kp-1> <f12> <down>
<kp-1> <C-kp-8> C-z C-h l

[back]
```

It's up to you to figure out which keystrokes go together to form a single command sequence, like the C-x C-s in the example.

To find out what a particular key sequence does, hit C-h k followed by the key sequence in question.